# Trying to use Chrome API topSites

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently trying to get the list of top visited sites using the Chrome API, [topSites](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/topSites). With the code below in my background page I am getting no luck so far, with the error code `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`. For reference, I already have the API listed in my `manifest.json` under permissions.

`background.js`

```js
chrome.topSites.get((arr) => {
  console.log(arr);
});
```

Comment: Without manifest.json I can only guess this code runs in the wrong context e.g. you're loading the script in `content_scripts` or you didn't reload the extension on `chrome://extensions` page. See also [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/a/10258029) just in case.

Comment: Do you know of any examples of how this code is used? I thought the placement of the code was in the right place since in the same context I am using the `chrome.storage` api and that one works well.

Comment: My guess was about a common pitfall: [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) can only use 3 extension APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for my problem, I did not update the extension package to use the chrome API topSites. I had to press `load unpacked` and update.